# Creating synchronized calls and passing values in a modularized node.js app with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I'm working on a node.js/express app to check details on a user's account to determine if they meet criteria to login to a resource. Originally, all of the code was in a single app.js file, but now I'm trying to break it up into modules so it can be used for multiple locations and resources, each with their own specific criteria. The app works by receiving a username and password in a querystring, which I parse into it's respective pieces. The username and password are then formatted into an API call to check that the credentials are valid. If they are valid, the script then retrieves more information from their account, and is supposed to check the returned values against the requirements for gaining access to the resource.

I've managed to set up directories and routes that correctly direct the request to the right script. I'm having trouble converting my API calls into utilities that can be used in multiple scripts (making the calls doesn't require changing the utility, but each script has different criteria to compared the returned values against).

I'm running into two problems. First, I have multiple functions that need to run synchronously, and they're being called before the previous calls complete, so the values they need to make their calls are still undefined when they start. Second, I can't quite figure out how to pass the returned value from the utility back to the login script.

Here's the contents of the login module:

```
var request = require('request');
const pAuth = require('../../utils/authPatron');

var username = '';
var password = '';
var bNumber ='';

var resource = {

    authenticate: (req, res, next) => {
    username = req.query.username;
    password = req.query.password;  
    console.log('Starting authentication');
    console.log(username, password);
    if (username.length < 9 || password.length != 4) {
        sendFalse(req, res);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Calling pAuth');
        return pAuth(username, password, function(bNumber) {
            console.log(bNumber)
            next();
        }); 
    }       
    },

    criteriaCheck1: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(bNumber);
    console.log('Starting criteriaCheck1 process.');
    next();
    },

    criteriaCheck2: (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Starting criteriaCheck2 process.');
    next();
    }
};
```

Authenticate parses the username and password and saves them as variables the whole script will have access to (is there an easier way to do that?), it then calls the utility pAuth and passes username and password. The pAuth utility has this code:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = (barcode, pin, bNumber) => {
        console.log('Running authenticate utility');
        var data = JSON.stringify({'barcode': barcode, 'password': password});
        var result = null;
        request({
            headers: {defines customer headers},
            url: 'urlToRetrievePatronInfo.somedomain',
            body: data,
            method: 'POST',
        }, function (err, resp, body) {
            var resBody = JSON.parse(body);
            if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log('Successfully authenicated');
                var bNumber = resBody.patronKey
                console.log(bNumber);
                return bNumber;
            }
    });
}
```

Authenticate is passing the query values into pAuth correctly. pAuth is retrieving the bNumber, but for some reason, I can't pass it back into authenticate. Also, criteriaCheck is being called before authenticate happens. I tried to create a callback function for pAuth and to move next(); into the callback function, so it wouldn't be called until authenticate finished, but the callback function is never being called and the request is hanging up in between the two.

So, how do I prevent the other criteriaCheck functions from being called before authenticate finishes? Also, how do I pass the result from pAuth into criteriaCheck?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is hard to read but something does not add up here:

```
console.log('Calling pAuth');
return pAuth(username, password, function(bNumber) {
    console.log(bNumber)
    next();
});
```

And here:

```
if (resp.statusCode == 200) {

    console.log('Successfully authenicated');
    var bNumber = resBody.patronKey
    console.log(bNumber);
    return bNumber;

}
```

You should probably do something like this

```
if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log('Successfully authenicated');
    bNumber(resBody.patronKey);

}
```

There are other issues with your code. 
Your call to pAuth is asynchronous, so ideally you should have this:

```
 console.log('Calling pAuth');
 return pAuth(username, password, function(err, result) {
    if(err) return next(err);
    console.log(result);       
    next();
 });
```

and your pAuth should be like this:

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = (barcode, pin, callback) => {
        console.log('Running authenticate utility');
        var data = JSON.stringify({'barcode': barcode, 'password': password});
        var result = null;
        request({
            headers: {defines customer headers},
            url: 'urlToRetrievePatronInfo.somedomain',
            body: data,
            method: 'POST',
        }, function (err, resp, body) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
                var resBody = JSON.parse(body);
                console.log('Successfully authenicated');
                return callback(null, resBody.patronKey);
            } else {
                return callback(new Error('Invalid response: ' + resp.statusCode);
            }
    });
}
```

You will also notice that I've made the callback function take two arguments: err, result. This is a typical nodejs convention and it allows for async functions to handle errors and success. If err is defined, error happened if it is not defined, it worked, and you should be able to read result.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry the code was hard to read, this is all new to me (I just learned javascript earlier this year), so I'm still learning some of the basics. Also, I haven't started working on the criteriaCheck1 or 2 functions yet, because authenticate wasn't doing everything it's supposed to. The changes worked perfectly, I really appreciate you taking the time to work through it.